# terraform: error while loading shared libraries: libpthread.so.0: failed to map segment from shared object: Error 14

Tags: linux, terraform

Installed terraform on fedora using `yum install terraform`.
I see `terraform: error while loading shared libraries: libpthread.so.0: failed to map segment from shared object: Error 14` when invoking terraform command.

`sudo find / -name \*libpthread*.so*` yields

```
/usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
/usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0
/usr/lib64/libpthread.so
```

What does the error mean? How can I fix it?

Some other posts for a slightly different error suggested creating a symbolic link

```
bash-4.2# sudo ln -s libpthread.so libpthread.so.0
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'libpthread.so.0': File exists
```

Doing an `ls -lart` in /usr/lib64 shows this symlink
`lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       18 Jul 26 16:08 libpthread.so.0 -> libpthread-2.17.so`

I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env. variable

```
bash-4.2# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib64
```

I also did `sudo ldconfig`

Comment: Follow the instructions defined here for CentOS/Debian: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/aws-get-started/install-cli.

Comment: ```bash-4.2# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Oracle Linux Server"
VERSION="7.9"
ID="ol"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.9"
PRETTY_NAME="Oracle Linux Server 7.9"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:oracle:linux:7:9:server"
HOME_URL="https://linux.oracle.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/oracle/oracle-linux"``` This tells me I'm on Fedora? I followed instructions to install terraform for fedora but still getting the same error.

Comment: Which package manager are you using? If it's `yum`, you can try with instructions for CentOS/RHEL.

Comment: Terraform is a statically linked binary, and so this linker error would be sourced from somewhere else in your system environment.

Comment: @MarkoE, the installation instructions include pointing to the right repo based on the OS...I've tried them all but no luck.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, that is correct. Here's what I'm trying to do. I have an ARM architecture based machine...I start a docker container with an image built for AMD using the "-platform" flag. Does that help identify a root cause?